# How to add punctuation around string?

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I want to add Square brackets around words identified as NNS. Able to identify it as individual words how to rejoin it with the sentences.

```
import spacy, re

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
s = u"The cats woke up but the dogs slept."

doc = nlp(s)
for token in doc:
    if (token.tag_ == 'NNS'):
        print ([token])
```

Current result:

```
[cats]
[dogs]
```

Expected result:

```
The [cats] woke up but the [dogs] slept.
```

Comment: Don't do that unless it's just for humans to look. If you manipulate the output into a string and the later read it again by writing a parser you're creating more problems for yourself when trying to parse the string format that you've created for little reason ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common idiom is to use a list to collect words and then join them:

```
sentence = []
doc = nlp(s)
for token in doc:
    if (token.tag_ == 'NNS'):
        sentence.append('[' + token + ']')
    else:
        sentence.append(token)

sentence = ' '.join(sentence)
```

Answer (score 2):

@John Blart, answer is correct an alternative using a list comprehension:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
s = u"The cats woke up but the dogs slept."

doc = nlp(s)
print(' '.join(['[{}]'.format(token) if token.tag_ == 'NNS' else '{}'.format(token) for token in doc])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
s = u"The cats woke up but the dogs slept."
doc = nlp(s)
sentence = []
doc = nlp(s)
for token in doc:
    if (token.tag_ == 'NNS'):
        sentence.append('[' + (token.text) + ']')
    else:
        sentence.append(token.text)

sentence = ' '.join(sentence)
print sentence
```

Result:

```
The [cats] woke up but the [dogs] slept .
```

Comment: Don't do this either  `"["+x+"]"`... Using formatted strings `"[{}]".format(token.text)` or `f"[{token.text}]"`